# Want to display HUD in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, mbprogresshud

I have created a app that record video and store it on server now i want to add HUD in my application ,this HUD will show until my data will store on server.

I am using MKNetworkKit fot posting data to the server.

I have tried this:

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    //NSLog(@"medea type is: %@ ",mediaType);

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
      //  NSLog(@"got a movie");
        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
        == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

        NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                                UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
        if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath,self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        } 
    }

    self.flUploadEngine = [[fileUploadEngine alloc] initWithHostName:@"reneveledat.net" customHeaderFields:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *postParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"testApp", @"appID",
                                       nil];      
    self.flOperation = [self.flUploadEngine postDataToServer:postParams path:@"/dilipvideotest/savefile.php"];
    [self.flOperation addData:webData forKey:@"uploadfile" mimeType:@"video/mov" fileName:@"upload.mov"];

    [self.flOperation onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *operation) {

        NSLog(@"response string is : %@", [operation responseString]);

        response = [operation responseString] ;
[HUD removeFromSuperview];
        /*   
         This is where you handle a successful 200 response
         */
    }     
                           onError:^(NSError *error) {
                               NSLog(@"error : %@", error);
                               UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                               message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                              delegate:nil
                                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
                               [alert show];        
                           }];



    [self.flUploadEngine enqueueOperation:self.flOperation ];

    // for HUD

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.labelText = @"Doing funky stuff...";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Just relax";
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];

    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(doSomeFunkyStuff) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];


   }

- (void)doSomeFunkyStuff {
    float progress = 0.0;

    while (progress < 1.0) {
        progress += 0.01;
        HUD.progress = progress;
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

its done now

i have just added this code

```
[HUD removeFromSuperview];
```

At

```
[self.flOperation onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *operation) {

            NSLog(@"response string is : %@", [operation responseString]);

            response = [operation responseString] ;
    [HUD removeFromSuperview];
            /*   
             This is where you handle a successful 200 response
             */
        }
```

Comment: OK. Go ahead and add a HUD. Once you've tried and run into problems, come back here and show us what you've done and we'll try to help you solve those problems.

Comment: i have added it but ,i dont know how to add it so it will run until data stored to server,but anyway i have added my code here.

Comment: So what specific problem are you having? There's no question being asked. Please edit and explain what the problem is, and we can try and help. You went from posting a plan to posting a big chunk of code with no info about how it's not working for you. Add that information to the question, please, and actually ask a question. Thanks.

Comment: actually i dont face problem,but i am asking that how to implement my code according to my need,sorry if that rude.

Comment: You are added th MBProgress HUD to your view, is it displaying ???

Comment: what happens after that? You are not removing the HUD from your view, then how it disappeared ?!

Comment: i think its removed when doSomeFunkyStuff method end it,that what i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the MBProgressHUD in the view.

You need to remove it after the data is uploaded to server.

So you need to write the removing code inside the completion block and error block.

like:

```
[self.flOperation onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *operation)
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"response string is : %@", [operation responseString]);
    response = [operation responseString] ;
}     
onError:^(NSError *error)
{
   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];        
}];
```

Comment: But still i am using MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate and it will go all round completed before the data store any suggestion on making this animation go slow and complete when data stored.

Comment: For this you need to implement a custom activity indicator, or search one in http://www.cocoacontrols.com/